# Getting "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row." In phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here is the complete database

(removed link to google drive download, go to revisions if you have to see it. A simple .gif would suffice.)

So I'm trying to use the universityName primary key from the university table as a foreign key In the resource table. And every time I try to set it up using the relation view in phpmyadmin I keep getting the error "Getting "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bluemtn`.`#sql-28f8_332`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-28f8_332_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`universityName`) REFERENCES `university` (`universityName`))

Comment: You need a row in university with universityName existing prior to what you are doing. It's a good thing. It keeps you from adding junk

Comment: The university table has a Column called universityName. Spelt the same and has the same  varchar character length.  I'm trying to use that Column as the foreign key in the resource table. Which also has a column called universityName.

Comment: Right. How about the data

Comment: Right now there is no data inside the universityName column of the resource table. I was gonna set up the relation first and then use the drop down list that appears after the foreign key is set up to fill in the universityName column in the resource table.

Comment: Clean data then create fk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some spaces before and after a few of names in the universityName column that was preventing me from adding the foreign key constraint because mysql thought I had values that where not in my referenced table.

Comment: Exactly in my case!